# How to query columns with [] inside the names?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am working with python and sqlite3 to develop a query tool for an specific database. In this database, some columns have brackets inside the name to indicate the units of the value, such as: current_[mA].

At some point I do a query with multiple columns such as: 
"Select Name,Number,current_[mA],voltage_[V] FROM table"

But whenever I try to query a column with the brackets it fails to query or it does a wrong one.

I have tried to process the column name whenever it contains brackets, but I have not found a solution that works.

```
columns_to_query = ['Name', 'Number', 'current_[mA]', 'voltage_[V]']
query = 'SELECT * FROM table'
for col in columns_to_query:
    if '[' in col:
        colstr += ",[" + str(col) + ']'
    else:
        colstr += "," + str(col)
    colstr += ' '
    query = self.query.replace(self.query.split(' ')[1], colstr)
```

When I try to execute the query, I get the following error:
Could not execute query. Error description -->  No such column: current_

As you can see it stops on the opening bracket

What do I need to do in order to query these columns?

Thank you!

Comment: You can escape such names with `col = '"{}"'.format(col.replace('"', '""'))` (double up any double quote characters in the name, then wrap the whole in double quotes).

Comment: You also want to learn about `str.join()` and list comprehensions: `", ".join(['"{}"'.format(col.replace('"', '""')) for col in columns_to_query])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive about SQLite3, but usually you just backquote the field names if they contain special chars or reserved words:

```
Select Name,Number,`current_[mA]`,`voltage_[V]` FROM table
```

Also note that if you build SQL queries with string concatenation, then you are likely open to SQL injection attacks. You'll want to instead [use prepared statements with bound parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/python).

Comment: While SQLite does support this, it really is a MySQL-specific syntax. Use `"`, double quote, that's the SQL standard.

Comment: It worked using back quotes. Thanks! :)

Comment: It also works with the double quotes as @MartijnPieters said. I will use that approach since is SQL standard. Thank you all!